# elasticsearch 5: Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [filters]

Tags: elasticsearch

Im trying to migrate from elasticsearch 1.7 to 5.1 and I have a problem:

```
curl -XGET http://127.0.0.1:9200/openlist_ru-formulars/formular/_search?pretty=true -d '{
    "filter": [
        { "range": { "born": { "gte": "1874" }}}
    ]
}'
```

and answer:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [filters].",
        "line" : 2,
        "col" : 12
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [filters].",
    "line" : 2,
    "col" : 12
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I used google all the day but still have no answer what it means. Please help.

Comment: sry, destination is elasticsearch 5.0.1

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It looks like DSL structure in 5.1 version was changed and this query is good:

```
{
    "query": { 
        "bool": {
            "filter": [{
                "range": {
                    "born": {
                        "gte": "1874"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```